# how to know if the SQL query PDO is empty?

Tags: php, pdo

I begin to despair, because I do not make a condition, if the result of the request for PDO is empty ...here is the code I use:

```
try
{
    $pdo=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MyDataBase','root','');
}
catch (Exception $e)
  {
    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
  }

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Mytable WHERE name=".$name;

if ($res = $bdd->query($sql)){
  echo" this name exist ";
}
else {
  echo "No rows matched the query.";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ues this...

```
     $name= $_POST['name'];


        try
        {
            $pdo=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MyDataBase','root','');
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
          {
            die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
          }

        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Mytable WHERE name=".$name;
        $res = $pdo->query($sql);
        $row = $res->fetchColumn();
        if ($row){
          echo" this name exist ";
    }
       else {
          echo "No rows matched the query.";
       }
```

It should `$pdo` instead in `$bdd` in query statement...basically a typo..thats all

Comment: yes it true, I have not paid attention to that, but that's not the problem...thanks for your remark:)

Comment: Include this too `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` after setting PDO parameter..I have made changes in the code...

Comment: thank you this instruction has helped me to know where is the mistake ... but I see this test it does not work because it always shows me this:" this name exist" even if the name does not exist in the database.

Comment: this:Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ahmed' in 'where clause'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\signature\index.php:21 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\signature\index.php(21): PDO->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\signature\index.php on line 21

Comment: I have made some change in the code...You were executing the but you were not fetching the result from the query...I guess now it should work fine...Let me know if it doesn't.. ;)